# How long before stats and ratings display for new Chrome Extensions in Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Published a new extension and it's discoverable and displaying properly in the Chrome Store.

Folks have told me they have installed it and gave it a rating.

But, no activity displays publicly or in the developer dashboard.

Am I just experiencing a normal lag or is something broken?

Thanks!

Comment: Stats are usually updated once a day. Sometimes, the stats are updated twice a day, sometimes once in two days. Is your dashboard working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my experience, stats such as weekly users and the stats graph will update at least once a day, and sometimes twice. As for the ratings, they take about a day to show up. I am sure it is just normal lag, wait a day and see if they show up.

Comment: Is this still the same or has the lag time reduced?

Comment: I had 2 ratings and 1 review left 2 days ago.. but still not showing up on the public page 