# Chrome extension stats wont show

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I recently deployed my first chrome extension on the google web store.
I can only see 2 ratings in the stats and no users in brackets like other extensions. It has only been 2 days.
What should I do about it?

Extension link: [MarkIt chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markit-text-highlighter-a/gppkdamjnjjjbfpiopekeccgaigakcng)

Attaching the manifest file in case it helps:

```
{
"name": "MarkIt - Text Highlighter and Manager for Web",
"version": "0.0.3",
"manifest_version": 2,
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"permissions": [
      "storage","notifications"
    ],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "css": [ "css/highlight.css" ],
        "js": ["js/jquery.js","js/jquery.highlight-5.js","js/content.js"]
    }
],
"browser_action": {
"default_title": "MarkIt",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"short_name": "MarkIt",
"description": "Highlight lines of text across the webpages using this extension.",
"icons": {"16": "css/icon/icon_16.png",
       "48": "css/icon/icon_48.png",
      "128": "css/icon/icon_128.png"}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307771/chrome-extension-stats-not-updating) answered by a Googler, that it takes some time, usually days for the chrome extension stats to show or update. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736392/how-long-before-stats-and-ratings-display-for-new-chrome-extensions-in-web-store) is another user that experience that delay for showing the stats in Chrome Extension.